# Adjust point sizes or set point sprites in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to display a point scatter in LWJGL. However, I can't find a way for LWJGL to set point sizes or add sprites.

The tutorials I find on the internet are all using a C++ OpenGL binding. I can't figure out which methods to use.

This is the method that is called to render the scene. It must somehow include the commands to set the point size.

```
public void loopCycle() {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GL20.glUseProgram(pId);

    // Bind to the VAO that has all the information about the vertices
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // Draw the vertices and adjust size....
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);

    // Put everything back to default (deselect)
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the size (diameter) of points using [`glPointSize()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPointSize.xhtml).

The maximum supported size is implementation specific. You can check that range by checking `GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE`.